# Best option to show longer grid data with editable in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am beginner to angular JS. I want to show some huge columns with some data both editable and non-editable section. that means some of the columns are editable like excel edit. It is also support  sorting and filtering functionalities.  Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

**red color highlighted non-editable. blue color highlighted are editable one.**

I need suggestion in angular JS to display the above grid kind of look whether can i use ng-grid or normal table. currently i have designed with normal table with static data.

```
<table id="dmgt" class="table table-bordered validations-all">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Rx ID
        </th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">ICN</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">HCPCS code</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Service date</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Paid date</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Provider name</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2 provider">Provider ID</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2 ndc11">NDC11</th>    
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Product Name</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Form</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Strength(mg)</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Units</th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2">Days supply</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1">Amount reimbursed</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1">3rd party liability</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1">Copay</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1">Patient liability</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue2">URA</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue2">Rebate per claim</th>
        <th class="bfcgrey3">Exceeds threshold?</th>
        <th class="bfcgreen"><img src="../images/quantity_white.png"></th>
        <th class="bfcOrange">340B</th>
        <th class="bfcYellow"><img src="../images/dups_white.png"></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Follow up,Dispute,or Ignore</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Follow-up reminder</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Follow-up status</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Adjust units + or -</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Savings</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Internal Note</th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3">Rationale</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div>
        </th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>    
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcGrey2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue1"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue2"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcgrey3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcgreen"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcOrange"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcYellow"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_gray.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_gray.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
        <th class="bfcBlue3"><div class="fLeft"><img src="../images/sort_random_white.png"></div>
                        <div class="fRight filter-flag" data-toggle="popover"><img src="../images/filter_white.png"></div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>074909</td>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>J1234</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>Harbor UCLA medical center</td>
        <td>1427259399</td>
        <td>12345-04-0134</td>
        <td>Iconomian</td>
        <td>Tab</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>5995.30</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="settings-B">Y</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="F"/></td>
         <td class="editable-cell validation-datepicker"><input type="text" value="02/05/2016"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="Open"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="-30"/></td>
        <td class="savings"> 30</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>074909</td>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>J1234</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>Harbor UCLA medical center</td>
        <td>1427259399</td>
        <td>12345-04-0134</td>
        <td>Iconomian</td>
        <td>Tab</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>71.17</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td class="settings-q">Y</td>
        <td class="settings-B">Y</td>
        <td class="settings-d">Y</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="F"/></td>
         <td class="editable-cell validation-datepicker"><input type="text" value="02/05/2016"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="Open"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="-30"/></td>
        <td class="savings"> 30</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>074909</td>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>J1234</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>Harbor UCLA medical center</td>
        <td>1427259399</td>
        <td class="NDC11">12345-04-0134</td>
        <td>Iconomian</td>
        <td>Tab</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>71.17</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="settings-B">Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="F"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell validation-datepicker"><input type="text" value="03/05/2016"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="Open"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="-30"/></td>
        <td class="savings"> 30</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>074909</td>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>J1234</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>10/31/15</td>
        <td>Sierra view district hospital</td>
        <td>1427259399</td>
        <td>12345-04-0134</td>
        <td>Iconomian</td>
        <td>Tab</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>33.09</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td >Y</td>
        <td >Y</td>
        <td class="settings-d">Y</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="F"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell validation-datepicker"><input type="text" value="01/05/2016"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="Open"/></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><input type="text" value="-30"/></td>
        <td class="savings"> 30</td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>
        <td class="editable-cell"><textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5">Sent mail on 8/28 asking...</textarea></td>


      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

what is the best way to achieve the above grid in angular JS. can i use normal table or any other way ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly straightforward: all you need to do is to build the table using dynamic data (which you probably already knew) and then have two different types of cells - editable & non-editable.

On editable cells you'll have the content within a text field so user can change it and Angular will update the model for you automatically.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: ng-grid works just fine for this and has all the features out-of-the-box: conditional cell editing, sorting and filtering.

Comment: Already i have implemented like that only. i want suggestion like can i use angular js grid normal table

Comment: Yes, ng-grid is probably your best option as it has most of the functionality you need out of the box, including the ability to define only some cells are editable* and the "excel-like" behaviour you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've had so much pain doing this in the past, but it was early days of Angular with very little resources.

I would recommend using something like http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/. Based on your description it does exactly that. I personally have no experience of ngHandsontable, but I know the pure JS version is pretty awesome https://handsontable.com/examples.html?headers.